# Is there a way to use static member as an interface in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, generics, static

is there a way to use static member as an interface for multi models in dart?

for example I can use interface normally as the example below.

```
interface class InterFace{
 String get task=>'';
}

class Task1 implements InterFace{
  @override
 String get task => 'task1';
  
}
class Task2 implements InterFace{
 @override
  get task => 'task2';
}

String getTask(InterFace interFace)=>interFace.task;
```

how can I use it if "task" getter is static ?

or is there a way to use generic type to get static member for Task1 and Task2

```
class Task1 {

static String get task => 'task1';
  
}
class Task2 {

 static get task => 'task2';
}

// like this
String getTask<T>()=> ??.task;
```

Comment: Statics are not inherited, so they cannot contribute to an interface.

Comment: is there other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

static members are not belong to the object made with class but to the type itself , so in this way it will not be possible to user static member via inheritance.May be you will explain what are you trying we can provide other solution?

Comment: In the last code snippet, I tried to clarify that I want the getTask function to return the value based on the class name without specifying the class. In other words, I want it to be generic.

Comment: got it , don't think that there is a way to access static properties via generic, the only way is to run some switch case like case T is Task2 got with Task2.task but don't think that it will help you